# How to fetch xml data based on attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xslt, plsql

For eg This is my xml data
[XML data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLyp1.png)

I have to prepare an XSLT to handle above type of xml. Here "description" node can come twice if it also has welsh text corressponding to english text and it will come with language attribute..So my requirement is to fetch text under description node with language='W' when it contains some text...else i have to fetch english text coming under "Description" node without language attribute

Can you please help with adding this type of filter in XSLT?

Comment: Please post your code here, not in external links and post it as code, not as a picture. Also include the expected output and your current XSLT - see [mcve].

Comment: Note also that the document you linked to is not well-formed XML (unbound prefix) and cannot be processed by XSLT.